# Rubymine css code completion does not work

Tags: css, intellij-idea, autocomplete, rubymine, code-completion

Simple html file with attached css file. Code completion does not work. (inline css does)

I've spent lots of hours trying to figure it out. Hope this will save some time for those who are still struggling. See the answer below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Autocompletion will not work if Code Insight feature is disabled.
So my problem was with the big css file. Actually, it's a regular size file (tailwind css processed by postcss with autoprefixer plugin).
Css file was around 3MB, but code insight stops working for files that bigger than 2.5MB by default.

The solution is to increase filesize limit.

Go to Help > Edit Custom Properties

Paste config

```
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE should provide code assistance for.
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=10000
```

Save and restart